# Can't turn off MulticastLoopback on UdpClient

Tags: c#, udp, broadcast, udpclient, loopback

I am sending directed broadcast packets from a UdpClient.

I am also listening on the target port on a second UdpClient (in the same app).

I do not want to see packets created by myself, so I thought it would just be a case of setting MulticastLoopback to false, but this does not work. I still see my own packets.

```
 private readonly IPAddress BroadcastAddress = IPAddress.Parse("169.254.255.255");
 private const int Port = 0x88a4;

 private UdpClient _udpSend, _udpReceive;

 private void InitUdp()
 {
     _udpSend = new UdpClient();
     _udpSend.EnableBroadcast = true;
     _udpSend.MulticastLoopback = false;
     _udpSend.Connect(BroadcastAddress, Port);

     _udpReceive = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port));
     _udpReceive.MulticastLoopback = false;
     _udpReceive.BeginReceive(OnUdpPacket, null);           
 }
```

Any ideas anyone?

Am I able to achieve this with UdpClient or do I have to drop back to raw Sockets instead?

**EDIT:**

I've tried using a single UdpClient instance for both sending and recieving, but now I never receive any data, regardless of the MulticastLoopback setting!

I have tried listening on both IPAddress.Any, and my local IP, but I never see any packets.

```
 private readonly IPAddress BroadcastAddress = IPAddress.Parse("169.254.255.255");
 private const int Port = 0x88a4;

 private UdpClient _udpClient;

 private void InitUdp()
 {
     _udpClient= new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port));
     _udpClient.Connect(BroadcastAddress, Port);
     _udpClient.BeginReceive(OnUdpPacket, null);           
 }
```

Comment: any reason you bind to `IPAddress.Any` ?

Comment: I tried binding to BroadcastAddress but I get an Exception "The requested address is not valid in its context". Googling seemed to indicate that this was normal.

Comment: I am not suggesting binding to broadcast but to a specific IP address...

Comment: I need to be able to respond to packets broadcast from any other machine, so can't use a specific IP.

Comment: Using a specific on the receiving side allows you to receive packets from any machine - as long as your IP is either directly targeted or part of the according broadcast-group.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but just tried listening on my local IP only, and still seeing the packets I'm broadcasting from _udpSend. :(

Comment: which OS are you using ?

Comment: How is your firewall etc. configured ?

Comment: Firewall is fine. I can see the packets on the wire with Wireshark, I just don't want to see them in my code! :-)

Comment: I think the property affects whether you receive packets sent *on that instance*, not about two different instances on the same machine (which could, after all, be in different processes, running under different accounts)

Comment: So can I send and receive on the same instance? I tried to do this originally but it wouldn't work. Probably because of the exception I was getting above. I will have another go.